# how I download button in report?

Tags: charts, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I want to make a report in cognos.I put chart in my report. And when I run the report , if I right click on chart I see the download chart option. I want to this option(download chart) on my report. I mean I dont want to need right click on chart.I want to see a button which when I click on it I download the chart.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in button within report studio for this.  You will need to insert a button in an html item, if your consumers are running IE you can use

```
 document.execCommand('SaveAs','true','http://chartsfilename.jpg')
```

as the javascript for it to run.  You will also need a way to dynamically derive the chart's url.  I would imagine you'll need some javascript for this, without having an environment to test on currently I would point you to http://www.ironsidegroup.com/2011/09/27/ibm-cognos-and-javascript-%E2%80%93-part-ii/